# ¿Cómo obtener la suma de una suma en SQL plano?

Tags: sql

Tengo por ejemplo esta suma en una consulta:

```
SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum
```

El resultado después de hacer la consulta es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el código anterior obtengo las sumas de la columna `e.tot_doc_che`, pero me gustaría hacer la suma de ese sumatorio algo como `SUM(SUM(e.tot_doc_che)) as sumaTotalDoc`. Lo cual no me deja hacerlo y me da error porque no se pueden anidar funciones de agregación. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto en SQL plano? Osea sumar esos 4 datos que salen en la imagen basicamente

Gracias

Consulta completa:

```
 SELECT m.nombre,
       SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum, 
       SUM(e.tot_imp_che) AS chequesDocumMontante,
       SUM(e.tot_doc_tra) AS travellDocum,
       SUM(e.tot_imp_tra) AS travellDocumMontante,
       SUM(coalesce(e.tot_doc_che, 0) + coalesce(e.tot_doc_tra, 0)) AS totalDocum,
       SUM(coalesce(e.tot_imp_che, 0) + coalesce(e.tot_imp_tra, 0)) AS totalDocumMontante
FROM Moneda m
INNER JOIN estadisticas e ON m.id = e.moneda_id 
GROUP BY m.nombre;
```

Comment: Podrías agregar la consulta completa ademas del esquema de la tabla que estas usando

Comment: cual es tu query? si sacas el group by no necesitas hacer sum de sum...

Comment: Creo que falta una explicación de por que necesitas haces eso o mas bien qué quieres lograr, porque lo que intentas hacer no tiene sentido, además las funciones count, avg y sum se ocupan con nombres de columnas por eso no te va a funcionar si le pones otra función dentro

Comment: @AndresGardiol ya la he puesto

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí lo llevas, editada pregunta

Comment: Esa query tiene 6 columnas... entonces, donde queres que salga la suma total? abajo de todo? si es eso, entonces es NO, sql no hace eso... eso lo tiene que hacer la vista, o hacer otro query...

Comment: ¿quieres agregar una fila con el total de todas las columnas?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho quiero agregar otra fila que sea la suma de las sumas de chequesDocum

Comment: una fila con todos los campos vacios menos ese?? eso deberia resolverlo tu vista... si no, tenes que hacer otra query que se una a esta.. es para solucionar algo en la pantalla, no?

Comment: pues eso sería SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum pero sin el group by. por esta razón, no puedes hacerlo en la misma query

Answer (score 2):

Como no has dado pistas del motor de base de datos que usas, la forma más general de resolverlo es mediante un `UNION`

```
SELECT 1 as Orden,
       m.nombre,
       SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum
       FROM Moneda m
       INNER JOIN estadisticas e ON m.id = e.moneda_id 
       GROUP BY m.nombre

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 as Orden,
       'Total',
       SUM(e.tot_doc_che) AS chequesDocum
       FROM Moneda m
       INNER JOIN estadisticas e ON m.id = e.moneda_id 
       ORDER BY 1
```

Una consulta trae los grupos y la otra (sin el `group by`) trae los totales. Fundamental establecer un orden para que el total vaya al final. Obviamente estas son soluciones que serían más apropiadas implementarlas del lado de las vistas y no en la base de datos.

Comment: El order no hace nada aca, porque se aplica solo a la ultima consulta.. o estoy mal?

Comment: No en un UNION aplica a todo el query, parece algo raro pero es así

Comment: Sobra el punto y coma en la primera parte y creo que sería mejor usar UNION ALL para no tener que ordernar 2 veces.

Comment: interesante.. buenisimo...

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Nombre' = case when grouping(m.nombre) = 1 then 'Todas' end,            
sum(e.tot_doc_che) as chequesDocum
from moneda m inner join estadisticas e on m.id = e.moneda_id
group by m.nombre
with rollup
```

En **SQL** existen las **cláusulas** **rollup** y **cube**, usando **rollup** podemos agrupar por los nombres de las monedas y obtener el total de cada grupo(subtotales), y posteriormente la suma total de todos los grupos o subtotales sumados, obteniendo de esta forma el total general. Aquí empleamos también la **función** **grouping** para saber cuando se trata de un super grupo o total general y darle como nombre en este caso el valor **'Todas'** al incluirlo dentro del **condicional** **case when**.

Aquí encontraraás un ejemplo excelente y muy bien explicado: https://programacion.net/articulo/cube_y_rollup_del_sql_266

Comment: @Sal, arreglado, gracias